# Elementary abelian vs. cyclic groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Sorry if this question sounds naive to someone.
What is (are) the difference(s) between an elementary abelian group and a cyclic group of a prime order?
Thanks

Comment: Definition: An *elementary abelian group* is a finite group where every non-trivial element has order $p$ for some prime $p$. Taking that on to Mariano Suárez-Alvarez's answer gives you what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the classification of finitely generated abelian groups, every elementary abelian group must be of the form $$(Z/pZ)^n$$ for n a non-negative integer.

Here, $Z/pZ$ denotes the cyclic group of order $p$ (or equivalently the integers$\mod p$), and the notation means the $n$-fold Cartesian product (*ref. [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_abelian_group)*). On the other hand every group of prime order is cyclic (*ref. for instance [here](http://planetmath.org/node/34101) or [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Group_of_Prime_Order_Cyclic)*).

Conclude that there exist elementary abelian groups which are cyclic groups of a prime order; but not every elementary abelian group is a cyclic group of a prime order.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb Z_3\times\mathbb Z_3$ is elementary abelian but not cyclic.