# Finite elementary abelian p-group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reviewing for an exam and i need help to kow if the theorem 7 in the joined website answer the following problem:

> Let $A$ be a finite elementary abelian p-group.
>
> Sow that $A$  is isomorphic to $C_p\times C_p\times C_p\times ....\times C_p$ for some nuber of factors.
>
> Hint: one efficient way is to choose $x\neq e$ in $A$ and consider a maximal element of the set of subgroup $B$ of $A$ such that $<x>\cap B=\left\{e\right\}$.

I found this web site [theorem 7](http://www.csus.edu/indiv/e/elcek/m210a/finiteabelian.pdf), i want to know if theorem 7 answer the problem.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: i edited, please help me if you could so. thanks in advance

Comment: To me, this is actually the definition of elementary abelian p-group.

Comment: It sounds kind of like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1688104/29335) might be what you're headed toward?

Comment: [This MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470546/elementary-abelian-vs-cyclic-groups) gives an answer. So Theorem $6$, not Theorem $7$ in your link.

Comment: but in theorem 6 we have $G(p_1), G(p_2).....$ and not the same cyclic group $C_p$???

Comment: why so, i didn't understand and i feel confused, can you please write down a more clear answer than what is given theorem 6? thanks

Comment: I did'nt understand what are $k_1,..k_l$ in this cas and where use the hint in the theorem ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, $A$ is elementary $p$-group, so all elements are of order $p$. Now you can use the Theorem 7: $A \simeq <a_1> \times H_1$ and since $H_1$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $A$, it is an elementary $p$-group, too. You go on in this process $A \simeq <a_1> \times <a_2> \times \ldots \times H_n$. At some point $H_n$ will be cyclic itself ($A$ is finite) and you're done. All these $<a_i>$'s are cyclic $p$-groups of order $p$ ($A$ is elementary!), so isomorphic to $C_p$.